# SQL Query: Does One to Many Relationship Contain Elements X

Tags: sql

I am building a reporting database and part of the requirements is creating multiple boolean columns to flatten 1:M relationships. Here's an example:

Table 1 is **Study Table** and has a unique id.

Table 2 is **Languages Table** and has a 1:many relationship with Table 1.

```
Study Table
Id    Name
1     Study1
2     Study2
3     Study3

LanguageTable
StudyId    Language
1          English
1          French
1          Chinese
2          French
3          Chinese
```

I want to have a few columns in my report table such as **Is In English** or **Is in European Language** i.e

```
Study Language Report
StudyId      IsInEnglish        IsInEuropeanLanguage
1            true               true                   
2            false              true
3            false              false
```

How would I build a SQL query to generate this table given Table 1 and Table2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   select s.StudyId,
          max(case when Language='English' then 1 else 0 end) IsInEnglish,
          max(case when Language in ('English','French') then 1 else 0 end) IsInEuropeanLanguage
     from study s
left join languages l on s.studyid = l.studyid
 group by s.studyid
```